# Ubuntu 14.04 pyenv command not found

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Pardon if already duplicate but I tried combing through the forums but it seems I can't get anywhere.

I am trying to install pyenv in Ubuntu 14.04 by doing these steps.

INSTALL PYENV DEPENDENCIES

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm git
```

DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL PYENV

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

YOU WILL SEE THIS MESSAGE

WARNING: seems you still have not added 'pyenv' to the load path.
Load pyenv automatically by adding
the following to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

CLOSE TERMINAL WINDOW AND OPEN ANOTHER ONE

```
No command 'pyenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'p7env' from package 'libnss3-tools' (main)
pyenv: command not found
No command 'pyenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'p7env' from package 'libnss3-tools' (main)
pyenv: command not found
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Please help how I can identify what seems to be the problem since I tried putting the script in .bashrc and .profile and still when I issue pyenv after opening another terminal the command is still not found.

WHERE I INSTALLED PYENV.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ls -la | grep pyenv
ls: cannot access .gvfs: Permission denied
drwxrwxr-x 10 user user 4096 Jan 28 06:40 .pyenv
user@ubuntu:~$ cd .pyenv
user@ubuntu:~/.pyenv$ ls -la 
total 96
drwxrwxr-x 10 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 user user  4096 Jan 28 07:32 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 12550 Jan 28 06:40 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  7477 Jan 28 06:40 COMMANDS.md
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 completions
drwxrwxr-x  8 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    88 Jan 28 06:40 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 libexec
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  1092 Jan 28 06:40 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user   285 Jan 28 06:40 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x  9 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 plugins
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 pyenv.d
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 12420 Jan 28 06:40 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 src
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user  4096 Jan 28 06:40 test
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user   139 Jan 28 06:40 .travis.yml
user@ubuntu:~/.pyenv$ cd bin
user@ubuntu:~/.pyenv/bin$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  16 Jan 28 06:40 pyenv -> ../libexec/pyenv
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 731 Jan 28 06:40 python-local-exec
user@ubuntu:~/.pyenv/bin$
```

Answer (score 12):

The instructions are a bit misleading because `.bash_profile` is only sourced when Bash is started with the `--login` option (e.g. from the console or ssh). However, `.profile` is always used, so it makes sense to place environment changes there.

Add the following to `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"    
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Open a new terminal window and your `PATH` variable will be correct to run `pyenv`.

Comment: Hi logged in and logged out as instructed in the earlier forums, I did include the path
user@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/user
# What is inside the .bash_profile
export PATH="$HOME/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

Is there something I missed?

Comment: What happens when you run `~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv`?

Comment: is this what you mean?
  user@ubuntu:~/.pyenv/bin$ pyenv
No command 'pyenv' found, did you mean:
 Command 'p7env' from package 'libnss3-tools' (main)
pyenv: command not found

Comment: Actually, the whole thing: `~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv`. It's is not found with the bare name because the directory is not in your PATH, which you can verify using `echo $PATH`. The change to `.bash_profile` should have included it.

Comment: so the path should be this?
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
How can I edit below to reflect the correct path?
export PATH="$HOME/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

Comment: PATH should include `~/.pyenv/bin`  is your shell bash? you may want to simply modify `~/.profile` with the suggested changes.

Comment: so @ Ben Grimm
  export PATH="$HOME/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH" will be
  export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH

Comment: Hi could anybody please help with the path I need to configure?  I am just starting with linux command lines and still trying to learn but I do need to run pyenv on 14.04.

Comment: Did you try running the export PATH, and then running pyenv?

Comment: could you please type the exact export command path based on the outputs I have shown you?  Since I do not know what is missing on my syntax...  Really appreciate this.

Comment: I updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

In the main folder *(the one shown when you open the file explorer, or you can view the path with the `pwd` command in the console)* use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>H</kbd>, and then find the file `.bash_profile` and add it at the end:

```
export PATH="$HOME/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `pyenv` you can follow the steps in below.

1. After successfully installed pip in your Ubuntu machine run the following command:

   ```
   pip3 install virtualenv
   ```
2. Once it is installed, check to verify that the installation has completed successfully:

   ```
   virtualenv --version
   ```

   If you get the output something similar `16.4.3` than you have successfully installed virtualenv.
3. Now run the following command to create a directory called `new-dir`, or another name of your choice. Then navigate to the directory.

   ```
   mkdir new-dir
   cd new-dir
   ```
4. Now create your virtual environment, named `newENV` or anything else:

   ```
   virtualenv newENV
   ```
5. And activate the virtual environment

   ```
   . env/bin/activate
   ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Don't use pyenv" isn't an answer for "How do I solve this problem in pyenv?".